# Is there a way to "hide" a sprite/button so it doesn't work at certain times?

Tags: javascript, code.org

I am working on a school project. It is a dress-up game where the user dresses up "Lucy" in three outfits. Everything works great until the dates (actual dates "Lucy" is going on).

The dates are just pictures I found on Pinterest. After each date, she would need to go back to her room to change again. However, each sprite background is just a layer and I draw layers on top of the previous one every time the user switches to a new screen.

It is really hard to explain, but every time I click on a `button`, another `button` at the same place gets clicked too. Although the second button can't be seen, it still calls that function and works. I used [code.org](https://code.org/) for this project since I couldn't find any other website to code that has an easy-to-navigate interface.

[Here you can see live preview](https://studio.code.org/projects/gamelab/Dmmo92fdr3g8nvilN-uPwcYS9TKF-Qk-Qb8iGqkcDkk)

```
World.frameRate = 60;

function date1() {
  if (mousePressedOver(startingbutton)) {
    instruction.visible = true;
    instructionbutton.visible = true;
    instructionbutton3.depth = 14;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(instructionbutton)) {
    showLucyRoom();
    instructionbutton.visible = false;
    instructionbutton2.depth = 10;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(schoolbutton))  {
    CropTop.visible = false;
    sweat.visible = false;
    dress.visible = false;
    school.visible = true;
    school.scale = 0.6;
    instructionbutton2.visible = true;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(sweatbutton))  {
    CropTop.visible = false;
    school.visible = false;
    dress.visible = false;
    sweat.visible = true;
    sweat.scale = 1;
    instructionbutton2.visible = true;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(dressbutton))  {
    CropTop.visible = false;
    school.visible = false;
    sweat.visible = false;
    dress.visible = true;
    dress.scale = 1;
    instructionbutton2.visible = true;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(instructionbutton2)) {
    showCafe();
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(instructionbutton3)) {
    showLucyRoom();
  }
}

function date2() {
  if (mousePressedOver(startingbutton)) {
    instruction.visible = true;
    instructionbutton.visible = true;
    instructionbutton3.depth = 10;
    instructionbutton4.visible = false;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(instructionbutton)) {
    showLucyRoom();
    stalker.visible = true;
    stalker.depth = 6;
    instructionbutton4.visible = false;
    instructionbutton4.depth = 10;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(schoolbutton))  {
    CropTop.visible = false;
    sweat.visible = false;
    dress.visible = false;
    school.visible = true;
    school.scale = 0.6;
    instructionbutton4.visible = true;
    instructionbutton4.visible = false;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(sweatbutton))  {
    CropTop.visible = false;
    school.visible = false;
    dress.visible = false;
    sweat.visible = true;
    sweat.scale = 1;
    instructionbutton4.visible = true;
    instructionbutton4.visible = false;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(dressbutton))  {
    CropTop.visible = false;
    school.visible = false;
    sweat.visible = false;
    dress.visible = true;
    dress.scale = 1;
    instructionbutton4.visible = true;
    instructionbutton4.visible = false;
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(instructionbutton4)) {
    showMuseum();
  }
  
  if (mousePressedOver(instructionbutton3)) {
    showLucyRoom();
  }
}

function showLucyRoom() {
  LucyRoom.visible = true;
  CropTop.visible = true;
  CropTop.scale = 0.6;
  schoolbutton.visible = true;
  schoolbutton.scale = 0.4;
  sweatbutton.visible = true;
  sweatbutton.scale = 0.4;
  dressbutton.visible = true;
  dressbutton.scale = 0.4;
  cafe.visible = false;
  museum.visible = false;
  instructionbutton3.visible = false;
  instructionbutton3.depth = 14;
}

function showCafe() {
  cafe.visible = true;
  cafe.scale = 2.3;
  text("This was super fun, I’d love to go with you again!", 28, 26);
  instructionbutton3.visible = true;
  instructionbutton3.depth = 14; // Ensure instructionbutton3 is on top
}

function showMuseum() {
  museum.visible = true;
  museum.scale = 2.3;
  text("This is the second date of the day!", 28, 26);
  instructionbutton3.visible = true;
  instructionbutton3.depth = 14; // Ensure instructionbutton3 is on top
}

var background = createSprite(200, 200);
background.setAnimation("StartingPage");

var startingbutton = createSprite(104, 228);
startingbutton.setAnimation("StartingPageButton");

var instruction = createSprite(200, 200);
instruction.visible = false;
instruction.setAnimation("InstructionPage");

var instructionbutton = createSprite(88, 372);
instructionbutton.visible = false;
instructionbutton.setAnimation("InstructionPageButton");

var instructionbutton2 = createSprite(240, 320);
instructionbutton2.visible = false;
instructionbutton2.setAnimation("InstructionPageButton");

var instructionbutton3 = createSprite(328, 354);
instructionbutton3.visible = false;
instructionbutton3.setAnimation("InstructionPageButton");

var instructionbutton4 = createSprite(238, 268);
instructionbutton4.visible = false;
instructionbutton4.setAnimation("InstructionPageButton");

var LucyRoom = createSprite(200, 200);
LucyRoom.visible = false;
LucyRoom.setAnimation("Lucy'sRoom.jpg");

var CropTop = createSprite(72, 220);
CropTop.visible = false;
CropTop.setAnimation("CropTop");

var school = createSprite(72, 215);
school.visible = false;
school.setAnimation("School");

var schoolbutton = createSprite(218, 138);
schoolbutton.visible = false;
schoolbutton.setAnimation("SchoolButton");

var dress = createSprite(100, 215);
dress.visible = false;
dress.setAnimation("dress");

var sweat = createSprite(72, 215);
sweat.visible = false;
sweat.setAnimation("sweatshirt");

var sweatbutton = createSprite(340, 138);
sweatbutton.visible = false;
sweatbutton.setAnimation("sweatbutton");

var dressbutton = createSprite(336, 310);
dressbutton.visible = false;
dressbutton.setAnimation("dressbutton");

var cafe = createSprite(200, 200);
cafe.visible = false;
cafe.setAnimation("cafe");

var museum = createSprite(200, 200);
museum.visible = false;
museum.setAnimation("museum");

var stalker = createSprite(117,236);
stalker.visible = false;
stalker.setAnimation("stalker");

function draw() {
  date1();
  date2();
  drawSprites();
}
```

I've tried using `.visible`, but that only changes whether the user can see it or not. It doesn't actually stop the `button` from responding.

Comment: PSA: It's 2024 and `let` / `const` are usually much better choices than `var`.

Comment: How would I use let/const?

Comment: There are many ways to do this but for code that already exist one easy work-around is to keep a `state` variable that you change for every state of the game (eg. "dating" or "changing" etc.) and just have an `if` statement in each button handler that check if it should execute its logic in a given state. Basically give up trying to disable the button but just disable your own logic instead.

Comment: Most of the time you can use `let` in place of `var`. It helps scope things better, especially inside of functions. Here you have an alarming number of "top level" variables that should likely be contained within something else, like a `class` as properties. You can create all those in your [`constructor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) function.

Comment: Anything you can do to reduce how much code you have also helps. For example, you repeatedly call `createSprite()`, then set `visible`, then `setAnimation()`. A helper function which does those all with one call would make this way easier to read, and you could even make your code more data-driven, iterating over an array of objects like `{ dress: { x: 100, y: 215, visible: false }, ... }`. This is one step towards defining your scenes in terms of data, such as JSON files. Changing data is easy. Changing code is *tedious*.

Comment: Maybe something like `if (sweatbutton.visible && mousePressedOver(sweatbutton))  {`. Check if the item is visible and, if it is, check if the mouse is pressed.